# How to Get array(fetch) and element in one line?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to get the array from database using php pdo fetch method and get the element on the same line.

something like this

```
($preparedStatement->fetch())['p'];
```

but it does not work. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of extra braces and/or insufficient PHP version. A correct approach would be

```
$preparedStatement->fetchColumn();
```

Answer (score 0):

On php 5.4 you can use array de-referencing.

```
function say_something() {
    return array('me', 'hello', 'how', 'are', 'you');
}
echo say_something()[2]; // prints 'how'
```

or :

```
echo $st->fetch()['p'];
```

**but not supported on previous versions of php.
so if you are working with php 5.3 or another previous version it will not work.**

you can use :

```
$st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

to select column number second column :

```
$st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 1);
```